# sendEmptyMessageDelayed : Android

Tags: android, handler, message, timedelay

Does this call block? Or is it in another thread and control can go beyond this statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't block.  The message is put into a queue.  This is then picked up by the Handler after the delay has expired.

Which thread is used to run the handleMessage depends on which Handler you use to send it to.